# Transfer data from Virtual Box to hard disk

Tags: virtualbox, transfer

How I can transfer data from Virtual Box 4.3 + Extended Pack installed in my Ubuntu? I try to connect an usb drive but I have fallen. I try with Shared folders and I got same result. I need a mothod (step by step).

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it is not able to use

```
netuse X:\\VBOXSVER\Folder
```

to find out the shared folder,

but if you first set the usb folder shared in virtualbox interface, then you should be able to find it out at windows 7 by windows expleror->Network->VBXSVR->(the shared folder), then you can map it as one of guest drivers.

Comment: I run Zorin Os in Virtual Box, not windows, a Ubuntu Distribution.